# factory_boy has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing, factory-boy

I am trying to write Django Tests. I get this error:

> .../lib/python3.5/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 118, in
>   _get_manager
>       manager = model_class.objects AttributeError: type object 'MyClassView' has no attribute 'objects'

Here is the setUp method (and imports) that fails when trying to set it up for testing. (The code running that generates the error)

```
import django
django.setup()
from app_name.tests.app_name_factory import MyClassViewFactory
from app_name import models

class Test_MyClassView(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.MyClassView = MyClassViewFactory()
```

Here is my model:

```
class MyClassView(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=2, null=True)
    division = models.CharField('Division', max_length=2, null=True)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=40, null=True)
    choice_objects = MyClassViewManager1()
```

Here is my Factory Class:

```
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory
import factory.fuzzy
import factory
from app_name import models
from faker import Factory as FakerFactory
faker = FakerFactory.create()

class MyClassViewFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyClassView
    state = 'WI'
    division = 'OP' 
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda x: faker.text(max_nb_chars=40))
```

My other factories seem to work okay, but MyClassViewFactory does not. I believe it is related to

```
choice_objects = MyClassViewManager1()
```

I've read documentation http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#custom-manager-methods for Custom managers on factory_boy but It only has a single example and I'm unsure if that is even my problem. (Spent several days on this now)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What version of factory_boy are you using? Checking the source code it does seem to handle the exception.. https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/factory/django.py#L118

Comment: factory_boy==2.5.2

Comment: Version 2.5.2 is dated April 2015. The most recent version is 2.9.2 and does use the Django model's `_default_manager` when `objects` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This error basically occuring if your model class is not inherited from the django models.Model. So "objects" is not available.
If you would like to use default django "objects" :

```
class YourClass(models.Model):
    ....
```

or add

```
objects = models.Manager()
```

as OP answered.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my models.py model MyClassViewFactory needed the additional line:

```
objects = models.Manager()
```

This allowed for progress, anyway!